# python ElementTree the text of element who has a child

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

When I try to read a text of a element who has a child, it gives None:

See the xml (say test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <test><ref>MemoryRegion</ref> abcd</test>
</data>
```

and the python code that wants to read 'abcd':

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print root.find("test").text
```

When I run this python, it gives None, rather than abcd.

How can I read abcd under this condition?

Comment: This was very annoying. It seams like 'abcd' is the text value of <test>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Element.tail`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) attribute:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>> print root.find(".//ref").tail
 abcd
```

Answer (score 4):

`ElementTree` has a rather different view of XML that is more suited for nested data.  `.text` is the data right after a start tag.  `.tail` is the data right after an end tag.  so you want:

```
print root.find('test/ref').tail
```