# Extract <emdash/> tag from XML in Python3

Tags: python-3.6

I need to extract the text inside 'text' tag using Python.

```
<titlePart>
<text>text sample 1 <emdash/> test sample 2</text>
</titlePart>
```

With following code I'm able to extract only 'text sample 1' but not 'text sample 2'.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

docs = dom.find('titlePart/text')

print(docs.text)

out : 'text sample 1'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python ElementTree the text of element who has a child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699889/python-elementtree-the-text-of-element-who-has-a-child)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am able to get the second string as well.

Comment: Glad to hear it!