# Reading an xml with nested tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have an xml file that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
   <p>
   This is an example of text <bold>just as everything else I write</bold>,
   this is some follow-up text that is hidden for eternity.
   </p>
   <p>
   This is more text with an <italic>strange</italic> example.
   </p>
</data>
```

I am using python to read it.

When I use the function parse from `xml.etree.ElementTree` and `getroot()` I get two `p` children. When I ask for the text in the first `p` children I get "This is an example of text".

If I look at the children of the first `p`, I get bold with text "just as everything else I write".

But I can't find ",\n this is some follow-up text that is hidden for eternity."

The same happens with the other `p` children.

Is there a way to get it?

Edit:

I'm confused because the only children appear to be the bold italic. I've attached an image with the code.

Example of code not working:

[image: Example of code not working]

Comment: Is there something other than getchildren or root to get all children? It only shows bold and italic as children of p. I've added an image if that helps.

Comment: The text you “can’t find” is in the `tail` property.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=tail#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail - and a tip in the docs at the link - to collect all text below an element use `"".join(element.itertext()).`

Comment: Many questions have already been asked where the main issue is the `tail` property on elements in the ElementTree data model (not knowing about it or misunderstanding it). For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19699889/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12412264/407651. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65506059/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/69679889/407651

Comment: By the way, please always post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: `ET.tostring(ET.fromstring(example), "unicode", "text")`

Comment: Using tail, as commented above and as the approved answer in the suggested question, solved the problem for me. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [itertext()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext) in order to get all text under `p`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
   <p>
   This is an example of text <bold>just as everything else I write</bold>,
   this is some follow-up text that is hidden for eternity.
   </p>
   <p>
   This is more text with an <italic>strange</italic> example.
   </p>
</data>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for p in root.findall('.//p'):
  print(' '.join(p.itertext()))
```

output

```
   This is an example of text  just as everything else I write ,
   this is some follow-up text that is hidden for eternity.
   

   This is more text with an  strange  example.
```

Comment: You are reinventing [`ElementTree.tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) method. `print(ET.tostring(ET.fromstring(xml), "unicode", "text"))`